# fix for image size in different browser sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the browser is resized or I am on a smaller or larger displayed monitor my slide images are skewed in size. When i'm on my larger monitor the image seems zoomed in.

http://www.bhhsall.com/the-monschein-team  is the site.

Comment: Maybe you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap css have it already, no need to write @mediaqueries in css. or you build your own css you should write @mediaqueries respect to screen sizes

**HTML**

```
   <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width:320px) {
 /* css style */ 
 // Example: .container {100%;}
}
@media (min-width:481px) {
/* css style */ 
 }
@media (min-width:641px) { 
/* css style */ 
 }
@media (min-width:961px) { 
/* css style */  
}
@media (min-width:1025px) { 
/* css style */  
}
@media (min-width:1281px) { 
/* css style */  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and you have to understand responsive design in Bootstrap you will get build in CSS class `.img-responsive`  by applying this you can achieve what you trying to do.

If you dont want to use Bootstrap then you can use CSS media queries to detect the screen size and apply you custom CSS to the image like this example:

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.jpg"
     data-src-600px="image-600px.jpg"
     data-src-800px="image-800px.jpg"
     alt="">
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-device-width:600px) {
  img[data-src-600px] {
    content: attr(data-src-600px, url);
  }
}

@media (min-device-width:800px) {
  img[data-src-800px] {
    content: attr(data-src-800px, url);
  }
}
```

here is the fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/7ghb25te/)